# XAgent importPackage vs. managed bean in none scope

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

What is your prefered way to run application (business) logic in an `XAgent`?

**XAgent using importPackage:**

*XAgent*

```
importPackage(com.test.model.configuration);

FolderConfiguration.updateFolders(
      facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getReader());
```

**XAgent using a managed bean in none scope:**

*faces-config.xml*

```
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>folderConfig</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.test.model.configuration.FolderConfiguration   
       </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>none</managed-bean-scope>
      </managed-bean
```

*XAgent*

```
folderConfig.updateFolders(
          facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getReader());
```

I am not sure about the pros and cons of both of them.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both versions won't be significant different at run time performance.

So, it's more a matter of code design.

Managed bean's pros:

- Java class reference is defined at a central place.
  If you change Java package later you have to change the managed bean 
  definition only
- JavaScript code is shorter

importPackage's pros:

- use of Java class is independent from outside managed bean settings
- Java class doesn't need to be instantiated if static methods only are called

I'd go for managed bean version if you use this Java class on several XPages or custom controls. Otherwise I'd use the importPackage or the direct call

```
com.test.model.configuration.FolderConfiguration.updateFolders(...)
```